Some questions about almost étale extension of local field
I'm in trouble understandig the example and proof of Example 4.2.2 in Denis Benois's lecture note about $p$-Adic Hodge Theory, he gives the following definition:
A finite extension $E/F$ of non-Archimedean fields is almost étale if and
only if
$$ \operatorname{Tr}_{E/F}(\mathfrak{m}_E)=\mathfrak{m}_F. $$
Then he says "It is clear that an unramified extension of local fields is almost étale" and give the following example of almost étale extension and also the proof.

Example 4.2.2 (1) Assume that $F$ is a perfect non-Archimedean field of characteristic $p$. Then any finite extension of $F$ is almost étale. Proof: Let $E/F$ be a finite extension. It is clear that $\operatorname{Tr}_{E/F}(\mathfrak{m}_E)\subset\mathfrak{m}_F$. Moreover $\operatorname{Tr}_{E/F}(\mathfrak{m}_E)$ is an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_F$, and for any $α\in\mathfrak{m}_E$, one has $\lim_{n\to+\infty}|\operatorname{Tr}_{E/F}\varphi^{-n}(α)|_F=0$.This implies that $\mathfrak{m}_F\subset\operatorname{Tr}_{E/F}(\mathfrak{m}_E)$, and the proposition is proved.

Here the map $\varphi$ is the Frobenius of $F$. I have some questions about this condition of trace map and the proof,

Why the unramified extension of local field is almost étale? If $\mathfrak{a}$ (resp.$\mathfrak{b}$) is fractional ideal of $F$ (resp.$E$), then $\operatorname{Tr}(\mathfrak{b})\subset\mathfrak{a}\iff\mathfrak{b}\subset\mathfrak{a}\cdot\mathfrak{D}_{E/F}^{-1} $. So unramified extension implies $\mathfrak{D}_{E/F}=\mathcal{O}_E$ and $\mathfrak{m}_E=\mathfrak{m}_F\mathcal{O}_L $, from these we can deduce that $\operatorname{Tr}_{E/F}(\mathfrak{m}_E)\subset\mathfrak{m}_F$. But how to see $\operatorname{Tr}_{E/F}(\mathfrak{m}_E)\supset\mathfrak{m}_F$? It seems that this is not directly from the definition of trace map
I can't understand every step of the proof in Example 4.2.2. First I don't know why $\operatorname{Tr}_{E/F}(\mathfrak{m}_E)\subset\mathfrak{m}_F$. I also can't see why $\lim_{n\to+\infty}|\operatorname{Tr}_{E/F}\varphi^{-n}(α)|_F=0$ and this implies that $\mathfrak{m}_F\subset\operatorname{Tr}_{E/F}(\mathfrak{m}_E)$.


I would think that the statement about unramified extensions is proved in any good source on local fields. At least the corresponding statement for norms instead of traces is kind of a cornerstone of the theory.

@TorstenSchoeneberg Now I think I know why the unramified extension is almost étale. But the proof of the statement about local fields of character $p$ is still confused me.
